# Make view transparent without seeing the text from bottom view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uiview

In the iPhone calendar app if you have 2 tiles overlaying ontop of each other the text from the bottom tile gets cut off and cannot be seen through the top transparent tile. How would I be able to keep the tiles transparent but not have the text from the bottom tiles show through to the top tiles?

Here is my code

```
APCalendarDayTile *tile = (APCalendarDayTile *)view;
CGFloat startPos = [APCalendarCurrentDayView yAxisForTime:[APCalendarCurrentDayView minutesToTime:tile.appointment.startDate]];
CGFloat endPos = [APCalendarCurrentDayView yAxisForTime:[APCalendarCurrentDayView minutesToTime:tile.appointment.endDate]];
tile.frame = CGRectMake(kLeftSideBuffer, startPos, (self.bounds.size.width - kLeftSideBuffer - kRightSideBuffer) , endPos - startPos);
tile.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:tile.appointment.appointmentColor]; <-- This also sets the alpha that makes it transparent.
tile.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:tile.appointment.appointmentColor alpha:1.0].CGColor;
tile.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
```

Tile code

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        CALayer *layer = [self layer];
        [layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
        [layer setCornerRadius:kCornerRadius];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.clipsToBounds = YES;
        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        self.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;

        tileTitle = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        tileTitle.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        tileTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        tileTitle.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13.0f];
        [tileTitle setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
        [tileTitle setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];


        tileDescription = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        tileDescription.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        tileDescription.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        tileDescription.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:11.0f];
        tileDescription.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
        [tileDescription setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
        [tileDescription setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];


        [self setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
        [self setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];


        [self addSubview:tileTitle];
        [self addSubview:tileDescription];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    CGRect myBounds = self.bounds;
    CGSize stringSize = [tileTitle.text sizeWithFont:tileTitle.font];

    if (myBounds.size.height <= 22.0) {
        tileTitle.frame = CGRectMake(3, 0, myBounds.size.width, stringSize.height);
        tileDescription.frame = CGRectMake(stringSize.width + 6, -1, myBounds.size.width, 14);
    } else {
        tileTitle.frame = CGRectMake(3, 0, myBounds.size.width, stringSize.height);
        tileDescription.frame = CGRectMake(5, tileTitle.frame.size.height, myBounds.size.width, 14);
    }
}
```

I would like the text in this photo to not show in the front tiles like the second photo.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you are going to -1 and vote to close, atleast post why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user1272965 is right insofar as each tile needs to know what tiles are above it, then you can get the text effect you're looking for by making the tile views a custom subclass and implementing their drawing manually:

Each tile will need access to tiles that are above it (or their frames at least):

```
NSInteger tileCount = [tilesAboveMine count];
CGRect framesAboveMine[tileCount];

for (int i=0; i<tileCount; i++) {
    framesAboveMine[i] = [tilesAboveMine objectAtIndex:i].frame;
}
```

In drawRect of your tile view, draw the tile, and then draw the text clipped by the views above it:

```
// draw aspects of the tile not to be clipped, like the background image.
// the setup for clipping:

CGContextClipToRects(context, framesAboveMine, tileCount);
```

then draw the text, which will be clipped by the frames above

```
[myCalendarString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(10,10)];
```

Comment: This sounds like it could work. I will try it when I have a few moments.

Answer (score 0):

I think the native calendar app squeezes tiles that occur at the very same start time as you do, but it also squeezes tiles whose times overlap, i.e. if the start time of the later tile is between the start and end time of the earlier tile.

But if you need your UI to draw these tiles overlapping, then there's no way around it:  the obscured tile needs to know that it's underneath (starting after and overlapping), and it needs to either hide its labels, or reduce their alpha level.

Comment: Hiding the labels is not how Apple does it. As you can tell from my screenshot you can see the top half of the letters. If anything Apple just changes the label size to match the top of the front tile.

Answer (score 0):

What about adding a `UIView` in between the two boxes? This middle `UIView` would cover up the letters (and have the same background color as the rear event), which solves your problem: no text coming through, but you'll see the color behind the other label!

You might be able to create the `frame` for this `UIView` using the frame attribute of the `UILabel` as well as the `frame` attribute of the frontmost calendar appointment.

Comment: The UIView has to be transparent so you can see the hour lines underneath them.